# Variadic template method

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I would to create a class method that takes variadic argument (in template) and then use them to get (for example) the name of the passed argument.

I tried to implements (but it's not working):

```cpp
#include <iostream>


struct St1 {};
struct St2 {};
struct St3 {};


class Test {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; // for example
    }

    template<typename T, typename ...Targs>
    void method()
    {
        method<T>();
        method<Targs...>();
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Test a;

    a.method<St1, St2, St3>();
    a.method<St1>();
}
```

And when I want to compile I get these errors, 'ambiguous':

```
testSpeed.cpp:29:19: error: call of overloaded ‘method()’ is ambiguous
     a.method<St1>();
                   ^
testSpeed.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: void Test::method() [with T = St1]
     void method()
          ^~~~~~
testSpeed.cpp:18:10: note: candidate: void Test::method() [with T = St1; Targs = {}]
     void method()
          ^~~~~~
testSpeed.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Test::method() [with T = St1; Targs = {St2, St3}]’:
testSpeed.cpp:28:29:   required from here
testSpeed.cpp:20:18: error: call of overloaded ‘method()’ is ambiguous
         method<T>();
         ~~~~~~~~~^~
testSpeed.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: void Test::method() [with T = St1]
     void method()
          ^~~~~~
testSpeed.cpp:18:10: note: candidate: void Test::method() [with T = St1; Targs = {}]
     void method()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17 this is pretty simple:

```
class Test {
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void method() {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) > 0)
            method<Ts...>();
    }
};
```

In C++11 you can do this:

```
class Test {
    template<class> struct Tag {};

    template<typename T>
    void method_impl(Tag<T>) {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void method_impl(Tag<T> tag, Tag<Ts>... tags) {
        method_impl(tag);
        method_impl(tags...);
    }

public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    void method() {
        method_impl(Tag<Ts>{}...);
    }
};
```

With a slight modification empty packs can be handled automatically:

```
class Test {
    template<class> struct Tag {};

    void method_impl() { }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void method_impl(Tag<T>, Tag<Ts>... tags) {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        method_impl(tags...);
    }

public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    void method() {
        method_impl(Tag<Ts>{}...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE to disable variadic version when parameters pack is empty:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Targs, 
    std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Targs) != 0>* = nullptr>
void method()
{
    method<T>();
    method<Targs...>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NPyvQk)

Answer (score 1):

argument of function allows to select overload, not template parameters.

One solution is to turm your template argument into parameters:

```
template <typename ... Ts> struct Tag{};

class Test {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void method(Tag<T>)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; // for example
    }

    template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
    void method(Tag<T, Ts...>)
    {
        method(Tag<T>{});
        method(Tag<Ts...>{});
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a;

    a.method(Tag<St1, St2, St3>{});
    a.method(Tag<St1>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb1c73b9a8fa0c76)

or

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

class Test {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void method(Tag<T>)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; // for example
    }

    template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
    void method(Tag<T>, Tag<Ts>...)
    {
        method(Tag<T>{});
        method(Tag<Ts>{}...);
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a;

    a.method(Tag<St1>{}, Tag<St2>{}, Tag<St3>{});
    a.method(Tag<St1>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9d43bda4bc63a1b)

But you can get rid of recursive calls (and of overloads):

Fold expression in C++17:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void method()
{
    ((std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl), ...);
}
```

In C++11/C++14, it is more verbose, and less clear:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void method()
{
    std::initializer_list<int>{0, ((std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl), 0)...};
}
```